# Problem on page reload redirects to login

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I created a web app that have a login page as home page after login it directs you to specific dashboards according to role, The problem is whenever I reloads the page it redirects me to login

> For example, if I'm on a dashboard assigned for admin when I reloads
> instead of reloading the dashboard it sends me back to login

I'm using custom createContext hook auth.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [id, setID] = useState(null);
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
  const [pwd, setPwd] = useState(null);
  const [role, setRole] = useState(null);

  const logIn = (id, name, email, pwd, role) => {
    setID(id);
    setName(name);
    setEmail(email);
    setPwd(pwd);
    setRole(role);
  };

  const logOut = (id, name, email, pwd, role) => {
    setID(null);
    setName(null);
    setEmail(null);
    setPwd(null);
    setRole(null);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ id, name, email, pwd, role, logIn, logOut }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

Here is my requireAuth

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuth } from "./auth";

export const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
  const auth = useAuth();

  if (!auth.email && !auth.pwd && !auth.role) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return children;
};
```

Here is my App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider } from "./Utils/auth";
import { RequireAuth } from "./Utils/RequireAuth";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
//rest
import ManagerHome from "./Components/Manager/Pages/home";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<LogIn />} />
          {/* Admin Routes */}
          <Route
            path="admin"
            element={
              <RequireAuth>
                <AdminView />
              </RequireAuth>
            }
          >
            <Route
              path="home"
              element={
                <RequireAuth>
                  <AdminHome />
                </RequireAuth>
              }
            />
            <Route
              path="profile"
              element={
                <RequireAuth>
                  <Profile />
                </RequireAuth>
              }/>
    //Rest of the routes
    </Routes>
    </AuthProvider>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my LogIn.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../Utils/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Style/logIn.css";
import logo from "../Assets/logo.png";
import axios from "axios";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";

const LogIn = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const auth = useAuth();
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleLogin = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/login", { email, password })
      .then((res) => {
        const user = res.data;
        if (user.status === "inactive") {
          setMessage(
            "Your account is disabled. Please contact the administrator for assistance."
          );
          return;
        }
        auth.logIn(
          user.id,
          user.username,
          user.email,
          user.password,
          user.role
        );
        navigate(`/${user.role}/home`, { replace: true });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response && error.response.data) {
          setMessage(error.response.data.message);
        } else {
          setMessage("Error logging in. Please try again.");
        }
        toast.error(message, {
          position: "top-right",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: false,
          closeOnClick: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "dark",
        });
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="logInContainer container-fluid">
        <div className="form">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="logo" />
          <p>Triton Consultancy</p>
          <form className="input" onSubmit={handleLogin}>
            <input
              placeholder="Enter Email"
              name="email"
              type="email"
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              required={true}
            />
            <input
              name="password"
              placeholder="Enter Password"
              type="password"
              minLength={4}
              maxLength={15}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              required={true}
            />
            <button className="customButton" type="submit">
              Log In
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <ToastContainer
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={5000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
          theme="dark"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default LogIn;
```

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

dotenv.config({
  path: "./.env",
});

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.HOST,
  user: process.env.USER,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE,
});

db.connect((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Database Connected");
  } else {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Database Not Connected");
  }
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());

// login
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [email], (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error("Error executing MySQL query:", error);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
    }
    if (results.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User does not exist" });
    }
    const user = results[0];
    if (user.status === "inactive") {
      return res.status(403).json({
        message:
          "Your account is disabled. Please contact admin for assistance.",
      });
    }
    if (user.password !== password) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Invalid email or password" });
    }
    res.json(user);
  });
});

// Create a user
app.post("/createUser", (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password, role, status } = req.body;

  const sql =
    "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, role, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
  const values = [name, email, password, role, status];

  db.query(sql, values, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error creating user:", err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Server error" });
    }
    res.json({ status: "Success" });
  });
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("listening @5000...");
});
```

Comment: can you make a dummy example of the react part here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new you can replace the login link for something like:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments

Comment: no it's my react code

Comment: You would not put all your code in there, just a dummy minimal version to be able to run, i tried copy and pasting the code you provided and was not able to run

Comment: Here is my Frontend code 
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-platform-nk45ms?file=/src/Components/Manager/View.jsx

Comment: Seems that the link is not available

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-platform-nk45ms